# Printing a specific dimension of a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor `x` of shape `(4,64,5,5)`. How can I print (or just visualize) the content of a specific dimension?

What I'm trying to do is

```
with tf.Session() as sess: print(x[0,:,:,:].eval())
```

but I got the following error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense_2/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense_2/kernel)
```

I'm using Tensorflow

```
1.14
```

Comment: Why are you using Tensorflow 1?

Comment: Because the paper I'm reading (unfortunately) has been implemented using tensorflow 1.14 and I'm not even a tensorflow user since I'm into PyTorch.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same in colab in Tensorflow version 1.14 using tf.ones(shape=(4,64,5,5)). It is working fine. Here's the code:

```
! pip install tensorflow==1.14
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

x=tf.ones(shape=(4,64,5,5))
with tf.Session() as sess: print(x[:,0,0,0].eval())
```

Output:

```
1.14.0
[1. 1. 1. 1.]
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!